# How to call a customly created url in magento

Tags: magento, url, url-rewriting, url-routing, custom-url

I have added one field in backend for adding url for Faq Post and successfully saved to the database.But I`m not sure how to call it back the url to display that particular post.My requirement is to generate a url for each faq categories post and have separate link to access them.
For example .If my faq category is Test and particular post in that category is test123.I want to generate link to access test123 something similar to {mywebsite}/faq/{faq_category}/{faq_post}.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Use "Url rewrite Management" when you save url in magento then also save url in url rewrite. 
You need to save in url table following fields:

id_path = "faq/{faq_category_id}/{faq_post_id}"

request path ="faq/{faq_category}/{faq_post}"

target path = "faq/index/view/cat/{faq_category_id}/post/{faq_post_id}"

you need to create controller View action in indexController of your module.
you can get parameter like this :

$category_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cat');

$post_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('post');

now run url {mywebsite}/faq/{faq_category}/{faq_post}